# prometheus in docker cannot reload config file

Tags: docker, prometheus

following this guide https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/management_api/

run prometheus in docker, and add --web.enable-lifecycle

```
docker run  -d \
  --name prometheus \
  -p 9090:9090 \
  -v /config/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml  \
  prom/prometheus --web.enable-lifecycle --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus --web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries --web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles
```

i try to change and reload my prometheus config.file in docker by

`curl -X POST http://??.??.???.??:9090/-/reload`

the logs shows

```
root@????:/# docker logs prometheus
level=info ts=2020-05-07T21:00:35.841Z caller=compact.go:441 component=tsdb msg="compact blocks" count=3 mint=1588852800000 maxt=1588874400000 ulid=01E7RF19SZ33YGN335TT7AJ571 sources="[01E7QTE3SVANFH1HPRXS2E07G8 01E7R19V1Y6ECYWKQKTBE6TPCX 01E7R85J9RQZYEMZP04X95ZX5S]" duration=321.581862ms
level=info ts=2020-05-07T23:00:35.949Z caller=compact.go:495 component=tsdb msg="write block" mint=1588881600000 maxt=1588888800000 ulid=01E7RNX0SV98R9ZEMH7EFN611S duration=689.868299ms
level=info ts=2020-05-07T23:00:35.960Z caller=head.go:662 component=tsdb msg="Head GC completed" duration=2.189158ms
level=info ts=2020-05-07T23:00:36.317Z caller=head.go:734 component=tsdb msg="WAL checkpoint complete" first=4 last=5 duration=356.868864ms
level=info ts=2020-05-08T00:17:06.630Z caller=main.go:798 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
level=info ts=2020-05-08T00:17:06.631Z caller=main.go:826 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

although the log indicates success, it is actually unsuccessful. what's wrong? can you help me? thank you

Comment: Do you have config file `/config/prometheus.yml` in your host system?

Comment: yes, i have. i changed ```/config/prometheus.yml``` and execute ```docker cp prometheus:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml /``` to check for changes. The configuration in the container has indeed changed.

Comment: ` it is actually unsuccessful` - what makes you say that? Can you add more information please?

Comment: it means i did not see any changes in `ip:port/targets` and `ip:port/config`.